# Properly delete an sqlite entry from a recyclerView click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

my app stores name and result in SQLite database and displays that in RecycleViewer. Previously I use a listView where on LongClick I could delete an item like here [LuckyNumbersApk/commit/4cec554359662d557626935046b8de68fb1b5c60](https://github.com/MyczkowskiAdam/LuckyNumbersApk/commit/4cec554359662d557626935046b8de68fb1b5c60)
now I have switched to recyclerView I can't handle it properly. When I delete it, it disapears but when I reload the fragment the deleted entry reappears again. I assume it because the item is deleted only from the list in the adapter but how can I delete it from the list that is in the fragment that actually calls the recylerViewer?

This is my Adapter:

public class DatabaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    List dataModelArrayList;
    Context context;

```
public DatabaseAdapter(List<DataModel> dataModelArrayList, Context context) {
    this.dataModelArrayList = dataModelArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CardView.OnLongClickListener {
    TextView name, result;


    public Myholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
        result = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_result);
        CardView cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp)
                .setTitle("Delete result")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this result?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        /* This is where deletions should be handled */
                        int id = getAdapterPosition();
                        DataBHelper database = new DataBHelper(context);
                        database.deleteEntry(id);
                        dataModelArrayList.remove(id);
                        notifyItemRemoved(id);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        database.close();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public Myholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    return new Myholder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Myholder holder, int position) {
    DataModel dataModel = dataModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(dataModel.getName());
    holder.result.setText(dataModel.getResult());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataModelArrayList.size();
}}
```

This is DataBHelper:

```
public class DataBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "results_database";
public static final String RESULTS_TABLE_NAME = "results_table";
public static final String RESULTS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String RESULTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String RESULTS_COLUMN_RESULT = "result";

public DataBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + RESULTS_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            RESULTS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            RESULTS_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            RESULTS_COLUMN_RESULT + " TEXT" + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RESULTS_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void saveToDB(String fname, String lname, String result) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String name = fname + " " + lname;
    values.put(DataBHelper.RESULTS_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(DataBHelper.RESULTS_COLUMN_RESULT, result);
    database.insert(DataBHelper.RESULTS_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    database.close();
}

public List<DataModel> readDB(){
    List<DataModel> data=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+RESULTS_TABLE_NAME+" ;",null);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataModel dataModel = null;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        dataModel= new DataModel();
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("result"));
        dataModel.setName(name);
        dataModel.setResult(result);
        stringBuffer.append(dataModel);
        data.add(dataModel);
    }
    return data;
}

public void clearDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM "+RESULTS_TABLE_NAME;
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}

public void deleteEntry(long row) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(RESULTS_TABLE_NAME, RESULTS_COLUMN_ID + "=" + row, null);
}}
```

And this is the fragment which loads recyclerViewer

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment {

DataBHelper database;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseAdapter recycler;
public List<DataModel> datamodel;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results,
            container, false);
    datamodel =new ArrayList<DataModel>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_recycle_view);
    database = new DataBHelper(getActivity());
    datamodel =  database.readDB();
    recycler = new DatabaseAdapter(datamodel, getActivity());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager reLayoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(reLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycler);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if (datamodel.isEmpty()) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return view;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onCreateViwHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Myholder holder, int position) {
    DataModel dataModel = dataModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(dataModel.getName());
    holder.result.setText(dataModel.getResult());
    holder.id = dataModel.getId();
}
```

Add long id; into the ViewHolder, so your onClick you can delete the   int id = getAdapterPosition(); and the id will be the id from the model.

To remove still use the adapter position:

```
                    dataModelArrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: Thanks, the item is getting deleted properly now :) Though recyclerView is not being refreshed after even when notifyDataSetChanged() is called